# multiple deletion in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { // TODO Auto-generated method stub //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

 String[] id = request.getParameterValues("hiddenID");
 //int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hiddenID"));

 foodDB db = new foodDB();
 Boolean success = db.deletefood(id);

 //Boolean success=(Boolean)db.deletefood("%" + id + "%");
 //boolean success=(Boolean)db.deletefood( F );  

 request.setAttribute("success", success);

 RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("delete.jsp");
 rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

this is my servlet part. Multiple deletion in database by using checkboxes selected. But it doesnt work.

Comment: What does not work? Any errors? Show your `deletefood` method, too.

Comment: @win not here. update it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This statement is wrong

```
 pstmt.setString(1, "%" + id + "%");
```

here `id` is a string array. So you are passing string array object to `setString()`. But not the array value.

Use for-each loop to get each id from the array `id`.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=null;

for(String i:id)
{
     pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
     pstmt.setString(1, "%" + i + "%");
     //now execute it

}
```

Comment: still no data is deleted

Comment: Is there any error? if `id` is there in database it should delete it. do you executing the query. Use sysout to check id. @win

Comment: in database id is null...it for Hiddenid